# How to plot graph between two timedelta variable in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

i have the following dataset :

```
Duration1                            Duration2
05:13:45                             01:09:58
18:53:38                             01:53:18
 NaT                                 01:03:38
07:19:38                             01:23:26
```

I want to plot a graph between the duration1 and duration2 ?

```
df['duration1'] =[" 05:13:45 "," 18:53:38 "," NaT ","07:19:38"]
df['duration2'] = [" 01:09:58","01:53:18","01:03:38","01:23:26"]
```

The datatype of the duration 1 and duration 2 are timedelta64[ns]

Bonus: Is it possible to get a function based on the trend of the graph plotted?

Comment: You cannot complain that the answer does not provide enough details, without supplying enough details in the question!

Comment: I agree. I made a mistake in selecting the options . And i couldnt edit it later

Comment: But you may still edit your question, asking exactly about the information that you would desire the answer to have. (To me the answer looks pretty complete and thorough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `dt.total_seconds`

```
df.stack().dt.total_seconds().unstack().plot.scatter(
    'Duration1', 'Duration2')
```

[image]

Easiest way to get the trendline is to use `seaborn.regplot`

```
import seaborn as sns

d = df.stack().dt.total_seconds().unstack()
sns.regplot(d.Duration1, d.Duration2, ci=None)
```

[image]

---

***code from start to finish***
*you should be able to copy/paste this*

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


txt = """Duration1                            Duration2
-1 days +05:13:45                   0 days 01:09:58
-6 days +18:53:38                   0 days 01:53:18
 NaT                                0 days 01:03:38
10 days +07:19:38                   0 days 01:23:26
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python').apply(pd.to_timedelta)

d = df.stack().dt.total_seconds().unstack()

sns.regplot(d.Duration1, d.Duration2, ci=None)
```

Comment: But i get the error - ValueError: day is out of range for month

Comment: @Irus I need more information than that.  I don't get that error, so I have no idea what line is producing it.